# Freezing Program When Clicking Button

Tags: vb.net

Code Directly Attached To Button

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim person As String = txtIn.Text
        If person <> "" Then
            If IsInFile(person) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Name Is Already In File!", "No Need")
            Else
                ReDim names(names.Length + 1)
                names(names.Length - 1) = person
                Array.Sort(names)
                MessageBox.Show("Name Added", "Success")
                File.WriteAllLines("Names.txt", names)
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Rest Of The Code

```
Function IsInFile(person As String) As Boolean
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt").Length
        If File.Exists("Names.txt") Then
            While x <= lines
                If person.ToUpper = names(x).ToUpper Then
                    Return True
                End If
            End While
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Sub frmNames_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        names = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt")
    End Sub
```

Only Import is System.IO
There is no Debug errors but when I type a name into txtIn and click the button the program freezes. It doesn't matter if the name is in "names.txt" or not so I dont think IsInFile is the problem

Comment: Use the debugger, Debug > Break All.  Decent odds that you now see a problem with the `x` variable.  Fwiw, picking good variable names is 80% of the battle.

Comment: Also, why do you check `If File.Exists("Names.txt") Then` after you have read its content? You can simply check whether a name is in the array already. You should use a `List(of String)`

Comment: Also, having you already loaded the content of the file at form load there is no need to read again in the click event unless something external to this code modifies the file. You have everything already in the names array (And I suggest you to change it to a List of strings instead)

Comment: If File.Exists is just a requirement for the function IsInFile. Professor wanted it there

Comment: Nope, your Professor wants you to use it **before** you access the file.

Comment: Nope. According to the book's example it is used in the IsInFile function. Literally straight out of the textbook. Just saying...

Comment: Nobody said **where** it's used (you can call that method whenever you want) but **when** it's used. That methods checks whether a File exists, to avoid accessing a File that doesn't and get an exception (here, unhandled, which would cause the app to crash). **Then**, if the File actually exists, you access it. No book in the planet would state the opposite. Unless you're reading a book about *creative cousine* or *alternative reality* instead of a programming one.

Comment: @Jimi In the books example If File.Exists is in the function like I mentioned. An Introduction to Programming with Visual Basic 11th Edition. Chapter 8 (Page 418). It's clearly used in the Function, not the main program which already accessed the file previously.

Comment: Again (3rd time): nobody cares **WHERE** (in what section of code), but **WHEN**. It's more than clear to anyone that you check for the existence of a File **BEFORE** you access it. Where this check takes place is irrelevant, but it **MUST BE DONE BEFORE** you access the File.

Comment: @Jimi AGAIN. The file is accessed BEFORE the function is called. I am not saying you are wrong, I am saying I am doing it like the text book. Let me repeat. The function in the book is used AFTER the file has been accessed.

Comment: 4th time (last time). In your `IsInFile()`, this is the sequence: `1) =>` Access the File: `Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt").Length`, `2) =>` Check whether the File exists: `If File.Exists("Names.txt") Then ...`. **FIRST** you access the file, **THEN** you check for existence. There's nothing else to say. BTW, this method is completely wrong, from the ground up, not just the sequence of method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `x` will never be `<=` `lines`, as you're not incrementing it. Include an increment in your loop:

```
While x <= lines
    If person.ToUpper = names(x).ToUpper Then
        Return True
    End If
    x += 1
End While
```

@Hans Passant included good advice in his comment. If you aren't familiar with the debugger, it may benefit you to re-visit foundational material relating to debugging your VB.Net programs prior to attempting any additional tasks in the language. Doing so could save you a significant amount of time now and in the future.

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb for missing that. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have been using a `While` loop in the first place. Use the most appropriate loop for the situation. If you want to do something for each item in a list then you should be using a `For Each` loop. `While` isn't even second choice in this case as, if you were going to use an index that you increment, you'd use a `For` loop

Comment: Furthermore, if you were going to use the third best loop option, you should be test for `x < lines` because your last index will be out of range and throw an exception.